# SQL Server 2012 Sequence auto-increment on success insert

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Im going to use SQL Sequence for storing a `folio` column value into my table.

I have seen when I call:

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR Test.IncidentFolio
```

The seed value gets incremented and there is no way to rollback the value, so I just want to increment my sequence when my insert statement hasn't failed.

Any clue on how to do that validation?

Comment: Why do you care about gaps? ProTip: Stop caring about gaps. If you care about gaps, stop using IDENTITY and SEQUENCE and roll your own serializable, extremely inefficient approach.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks, you are right. maybe Im worry too much about  it. Just wanted to give the user a way they always have a sequential ID on the reports they generate.

Comment: If the ID doesn't mean anything, why bother showing it? If they need it for row numbering, and again if it doesn't mean anything, just calculate row_number() at query time. Truthfully, surrogate ID values shouldn't be shown to the customer and shouldn't have any meaning at all.